# About AbstractCollection implementation

Tags: java, list, collections

I have looked abstraccollection and have found that **containsAll** method iterates through whole collection.
Why this method doesn't check a size for collections? In case when main collection has only one element  and a target collection has 100000 elements the performance will be decreased.

Also ArrayList has overridden method isEmpty that compare the list's size and 0. Why this method was overridden and overridden with such implementation? The AbstractCollection has almost the same implementation.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't check the size of the collections because the size does not have to be the same.

In case of duplicate elements in one list, `containsAll` can still return true:

```
AbstractCollection<Integer> first = new ArrayList<>();
AbstractCollection<Integer> second = new ArrayList<>();
first.add(1);
second.add(1);
second.add(1);

System.out.println(first.containsAll(second)); // Prints 'true'
```

To figure out why `isEmpty` is implemented like it is, you would probably have to ask the developers who made it. It could be that they wanted to avoid the overhead of a call to `size()`, in case it wasn't inlined by the compiler.

---

EDIT: Shail016 already adressed the issues, but I wanted to add them to my answer anyway.

> 1) what if first collection does not have any element at all

If it doesn't have any elements `containsAll` will return false on the very first `contains` check (it would not make any unnecessary iterations), so a check for size 0 wouldn't make much of a difference (and it would add an extra comparison to all uses of `containsAll`). Because of this, such a check was probably deemed unnecessary.

> 2) why HashSet rely on parent's method ?

It doesn't. It rely on `isEmpty` from the internal `HashMap`.

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return map.isEmpty();
}
```

And `HashMap`'s implementation is the same as the one in `ArrayList`

Comment: Ok , but there are two other issue:
1) what if first collection does not have any element at all
2) why HashSet rely on parent's method ?

Comment: @sbjavateam check contains in AbstractCollection and indexOf in ArrayList, the size difference doesn't cause any unnecessary iterations (performance overhead) or errors. plus may be the developers preferred using  available state of size by overriding isEmpty (as mentioned by MAV), these APIs are present since version 1.2, may be there was some minor performance gain in their minds.

Answer (score 1):

MAV is correct:

inspecting the containsAll() in AbstractCollection's source also tells that it doesn't need a size check:

```
  public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        for (Object e : c)
            if (!contains(e))//here its sort of size proof, also check indexOf in ArrayList
                return false;
        return true;
    }
```

`The method returns on the very first check failure.`(either size difference between two lists or very first non existing value)

also, hashset doesnt rely on parents method but on isEmpty of backing HashMap (which again overrides isEmpty like ArrayList)